# In Ruby, can you create a rescue for twitter for when there is an error it will continue the loop?

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, loops, twitter, rescue

I'm trying to create a `rescue` that if and when there is an `Twitter::Error::NotFound` error (such as does not exist) it will just keep going through the loop. Please help, thanks.

Below is the code,

```
begin
  File.open("user_ids.txt") do |file| 
    file.each do |id|
      puts client.user("#{id}").screen_name
    rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound => error
      next # skip this item
    end
  end
end
```

Instead of the `retry` method is there a a method that can skip and keep moving on to the next item in the loop?
I'm pretty sure the `error.rate_limit` does not apply (I copied this code from a different rescue call), is there another method to call? like `error.notfound.continue_with_loop`

I would like to create a rescue that if and when there is an error such as `does not exist` so it will just keep going through the loop. Please help, thanks.

Comment: yes `next` will continue and retry the next item in a loop. `retry` will retry the loop with the same item

Comment: ah okie doke, thanks @TarynEast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes `next` will continue and retry the next item in a loop.
`retry` will retry the loop with the same item.

Note: you don't have enough `end`s for all the `do` that are in that method. So I'd try:

```
begin
  File.open("user_ids.txt") do |file| 
    file.each do |id|
      puts client.user("#{id}").screen_name
    rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound => error
      sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in + 1
      next # skip this item
    end
  end
end
```

Note: see how proper indentation makes it clear when you're missing an `end` ?

You may need to shift the begin/end block that is currently around the lot - to just be around the code that you want to rescue-from (or it'll default to the outside begin/end rather than your loop)

```
File.open("user_ids.txt") do |file| 
  file.each do |id|
    begin
      puts client.user("#{id}").screen_name
    rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound => error
      sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in + 1
      next # skip this item
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting an error still saying   'twitter.rb:297: syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue, expecting keyword_end
    rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound => error
          ^
twitter.rb:297: syntax error, unexpected =>
    rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound => error
                                      ^'

Comment: I edited my above code to look exactly how it looks in sublime

Comment: Neat, thanks - it also helps when you do that here so we can easily see the structure and tell if there's something missing.... :)

Comment: You'll probably need to put a begin/end block around the rescue then.